# Need bin or hex file for Pic 16F648A Serial LCD

Tags: lcd

I have seen some kits and boards for a Serial LCD based on the PIC16F648A.
A have a few of the chips and a few LCDs. I'm not into PIC programming, does anyone have a link to the compiled software I can program my PIC chips with to make my own serial LCD?

Comment: How do you plan to feed data into your pic? This question is difficult to answer without knowing that.

Comment: Which LCD do you have? (Is it SPI, I2C, other?) And are you sure you want the *compiled* software? Kinda useless, as such.

Comment: I planned to send serial data like in the Sparkfun SerLCD_V2 spec. I don't know the brand of the LCD, it is a 4 x 20 with the parallel 16 pin header HD44780 type controller. I have it working on Arduino using the liquidcrystal library, but wanted to mount it remotely, since I had some 16f648 chips laying around, thought that would work. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiled bin/hex files are very specific and can not be easily adapted to your specific situation. This means that the bin/hex file would have to be for the exact PIC you have along with all of the exact pins connected as was designed for in the original code.

Also many companies protect their code and compiled versions of their code very tightly. This means that there is a good chance that they wont just hand it over to you.

So, likely you wont find an answer to your question. Instead you should look to see if someone has released information on how to build what you are looking for. It will require that you are willing to be open to learning about firmware coding as you will have to touch it to work on a project like this.

Comment: Thanks kellenjb - that explains why I had no luck in finding any. Would have only wanted open source if available. I'll dig in.